# After upgrading from CEFSharp 57 to 63 ChromeDriver "get" command does not block until the page load is complete

Tags: cefsharp

I am using selenium to navigate my CEFSharp browser.

After upgrading my browser to use CEFSharp 63 the "get" command response before the browser load the page. So I cannot get the correct DOM from the response.
This is happen also when there is no redirects and no JS that changes the DOM. 
It was worked correctly with CEFSharp 57.

How can I fixed this issue?

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: How does Chrome of the same version behave? Are you using the latest selenium? CefSharp is just a wrapper around https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: On Chrome 63.0.3239.108 the problem does not exists and I am using the latest selenium version. Thanks, Shay

Comment: You should include that information at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2402/after-upgrading-from-cef-57-to-63-load